# FindBugs reporting null pointer dereference

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, findbugs

I downloaded an application for my class and was instructed to run a build file that verifies that everything works. This build file invokes FindBugs, among other things and everyone's build file succeeds except for mine. FindBugs warns of a null pointer dereference of System.out. I am running Linux Ubuntu 11.10 with Java 1.6.0.23 and Ant 1.8.2, but this has never happened before on any of my other applications. I'm wondering if the Java interpreter is picking up something different or something.. It's not necessarily bad that it's doing this, but the question I want to ask is if there's any way to suppress this warning so that my build file can succeed?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, the problem isn't code-specific, because it runs fine on my Windows side. The "problematic code" is just a simple System.out.println, along with other System.out statements. It seems to be an environment-specific issue..

Comment: I use findbugs, but never had that issue. I understand now... If it's on bare println statements, it's a findbugs bug :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is a false warning, should be corrected in the last release.

Take a look [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3139802&group_id=96405&atid=614693) .

Comment: Yes, but my build file downloads the latest release of FindBugs, and it still gives this error. No such problem on Windows or Mac, though, but this error has never occurred for me before..

Comment: Are you downloading from nightly build repository ?

Comment: The download is based on Ivy, but FindBugs is confirmed to be version 1.3.9, which is the current stable release..

Comment: Well, not exactly, since I have it running on Windows now, without changing anything at all, and it's working just fine. FindsBugs 1.3.9 and all..